# Why add 1 when calculating height of AVL tree?

Tags: c++, avl-tree

While updating the heights of my subtrees in an AVL rotation implementation, I noticed in the example the code that the height function is

```
x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) +1;
```

Does anyone know where the `+1` comes from and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing any actual code, I'm assuming max(height(x->left, height(x->right) doesn't include the node you are calling the function on. Height function returns whichever subtree is higher and + 1 for your current node to get the total height.